# Convert original date and time to valid WORKDAYS and TIME in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, data-conversion, converters

Let's add some context:
So, I was asked to calculate days aged of emails sent to a particular email address. The source I'm using is SAP HANA and made a Live connection to it in Tableau. The field I have to work with is called **Created At**. This field holds the data in **yyyymmddhhmmss** string format.

**The challenge**: Convert the original date in `Created At` field to a valid Working day and time (Monday-Friday and between 7:00am to 5:00pm). This is what I came up with:

```
CASE DATENAME('weekday',DATETIME([Created At]))
WHEN '7' THEN //item received on Saturday
DATEADD('day',2,DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))))
    //first, I cut off the original time from Created At with DATETRUNC.
    //Next, I added 7 hours to get Saturday 7:00 am
    //finally, I add 2 days to change the date from a Saturday to a Monday

WHEN '1' THEN //item received on Sunday
DATEADD('day',2,DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))))
    //first, I cut off the original time from Created At with DATETRUNC.
    //Next, I added 7 hours to get Sunday 7:00 am
    //finally, I add 1 day to change the date from a Sunday to a Monday

WHEN '6' THEN //item received on Friday
    //item received before 7:00am (7hrs)
    IF DATETIME([Created At]) < DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))) THEN
        //first I cut off the original time from Created At with DATETRUNC.
        //Next, I added 7 hours to date to get the current date at 7:00 am
        DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At])))

    //item received after 4:00pm (16hrs) 
    ELSEIF DATETIME([Created At]) > DATEADD('hour',16,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))) THEN
        DATEADD('day',3,DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))))
        //first I cut off the original time from Created At with DATETRUNC.
        //Next, I added 7 hours to date to get the current date at 7:00 am
        //finally, I add 3 days to change from Friday to Monday at 7:00 am

    //item received between 7:00am and 4:00pm (7-16hrs)
    ELSE DATETIME([Created At]) END

ELSE //received any other day of the week
    //item received before 7:00am (7hrs)
    IF DATETIME([Created At]) < DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))) THEN
        //first I cut off the original time from Created At with DATETRUNC.
        //Next, I added 7 hours to date to get the current date at 7:00 am
        DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At])))

    //item received after 4:00pm (16hrs) 
    ELSEIF DATETIME([Created At]) > DATEADD('hour',16,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))) THEN
        DATEADD('day',1,DATEADD('hour',7,DATETRUNC('day',DATETIME([Created At]))))
        //first I cut off the original time from Created At with DATETRUNC.
        //Next, I added 7 hours to date to get the current date at 7:00 am
        //finally, I add 1 day to get next date forward at 7:00 am

    //item received between 7:00am and 4:00pm (7-16hrs)
    ELSE DATETIME([Created At]) END
END
```

Let me know if you have a better way to do this or let me know if you found it useful. Hope this helps!

Comment: this seems to be an answer in a question. You can always answer your own question

Comment: Tableau has fairly sophisticated data calculation functions, it seems like overkill to attempt to do all the conversions in SQL. Just convert the string in Tableau and use the built-in calculations.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's more of a comment rather than a question. It's just that I could not get the results I wanted using built-in calculations. Of course, I'm open to suggestions. Please post them here.